If a natural number, $N=2^{3}\cdot3^{2}\cdot5^{1}\cdot 7^{1}$ then identify which of the following statement(s) is/are correct?

If a natural number, $N=2^{3}\cdot3^{2}\cdot5^{1}\cdot 7^{1}$ then identify which of the following statement(s) is/are correct?

(A) The product of all divisors of $N$ is $(N)^{24}$
(B) The product of all even divisors of $N$ is $(2N)^{18}$
(C) The product of all odd divisors of $N$ is $\left(\dfrac{N}{2}\right)^{6}$
(D) The product of all composite divisors of $N$ is $\left(\dfrac{N^{24}}{210}\right)$
My Attempt: Total divisors are $(3+1)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=48$
Total number of even divisors are $(3)(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=36$
Even though I dont know proof of product of all divisors which $N^{\dfrac{d(n)}{2}}$.
After getting suggestion from @lulu
I've listed all the odd divisors of $N$ as $\left(3^{0}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{1}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{2}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{0}\cdot 5^{1},\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{1}\cdot 5^{1}\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{2}\cdot 5^{1}\cdot 7^{0}, 3^{0}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{1}, 3^{1}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{1}, 3^{2}\cdot 5^{0}\cdot 7^{1}, 3^{0}\cdot 5^{1}\cdot 7^{1}, 3^{1}\cdot 5^{1}\cdot 7^{1}, 3^{2}\cdot 5^{1}\cdot 7^{1}\right)$
And product of all odd divisors is $\left(3^{0+1+2}\right)^{\text{number of divisors of 5 and 7}}\cdot \left(5^{0+1}\right)^{\text{number of divisors of 3 and 7}}\cdot \left(7^{0+1}\right)^{\text{number of divisors of 3 and 5}}$
So formula of product of even divisors is $\left(2^{1+2+3}\right)^{\text{number of divisors of 3 and 5 and 7}}\times \left(3^{0+1+2}\right)^{\text{number of even divisors of 2 and 5 and 7}} \times \left(5^{0+1}\right)^{\text{number of even divisors of 2 and 3 and 7}}\times \left(7^{0+1}\right)^{\text{number of even divisors of 2 and 3 and 5}}=(2^{72}\times 3^{36}\times 5^{18}\times 7^{18})$
Hence Option (B) is true
But I am still unable to find Option (D)
Also is there any other method to solve option (B)

Please edit to include your efforts.  If nothing else, you should easily be able to deduce $(d)$ from $(a)$.  And the even divisors of $N$ are just $2$ times  the (unconstrained) divisors of $\frac N2$.


PART A

note that if $d$ is a divisor of $N$, then so is $\frac{N}{d}$ and hence $$\prod_{d|N}d^{2} \  = \ \prod_{d|N}d \frac{N}{d} \ =\ \prod_{d|N}N \ =\ N^{\tau(N)}$$
where $\tau(N)$ is the number of divisors of $N$. And consequently,
$$\prod_{d|N}d=N^{\frac{\tau(N)}{2}}=N^{24}$$

PART B,C

The product of even divisors of $N$ is the product of divisors of $N$ divided by the product of odd divisors of $N$.
But odd divisors of $N$ are exactly the divisors of $M=\frac{N}{2^3}=3^2 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^1$
We have $$\prod_{d|M}d = M^{\tau(M)/2}=M^{6}=\left( \frac{N}{8} \right)^{6}$$
And consequently, the product of even divisors of $N$ is $$\frac{N^{24}}{\left( \frac{N}{8} \right)^{6}}=(2N)^{18}$$

PART D

The product of composite divisors of $N$ is the product of divisors of $N$ divided by the product of prime divisors of $N$. But the prime divisors of $N$ are exactly $2,3,5,7$.
Hence, the required product is $$\frac{N^{24}}{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7}=\frac{N^{24}}{210}$$
NOTE:
Product of even divisors of $N$ can also be calculated as $2^{\tau(N/2)}$ times the product of divisors of $\frac{N}{2}$ as lulu suggested.
